# One function to serve two selects JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have two selects in HTML.

```
<select id="country">
  <option value="Sasha">--Wybierz--</option>  
  <option value="Egipt">Egipt</option>
  <option value="Afganistan">Afganistan</option>
  <option value="Serbia">Serbia</option>
</select>

<select id="country-bd">
  <option value="Sasha">--Wybierz--</option>  
  <option value="Egipt">Egipt</option>
  <option value="Polska">Polska</option>
  <option value="Serbia">Serbia</option>
</select>

var high_ryzyko_kraj = ['Polska', 'Afganistan', 'Ukraina'];

$(function(){
 $('#country').change(function(){
    caunt = $(this).val();
    scoring = 0;
        var arr = $.inArray(caunt, high_ryzyko_kraj)
        if (arr===1){  
             scoring =+ 4 ;
             clback();
        }
   });

 function clback(){
   result = scoring
   console.log(result);
   }
});
```

When the country in `high_ryzyko_kraj` array is selected I want `result` variable in calback function to be incremented by 4.

So Afganistan in first select and Polska in second select would give me total of 8. I need callback later on so I just left it there.

Is there a way of modifying my first function that it serves both `#country` and `#country-bd` ?

Link to JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/szymondzumak/TCx6L/1/

Comment: You should look at [Multiple Selector ("selector1, selector2, selectorN")](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Added new selector.
2. Declared scoring variable outside the change callback.
3. arr will be -1 when values doesn't match in an array.

Try this,

```
var high_ryzyko_kraj = ['Polska', 'Afganistan', 'Ukraina'];

$(function(){
    var scoring = 0;
    $('#country, #country-bd').change(function(){
        caunt = $(this).val();
            var arr = $.inArray(caunt, high_ryzyko_kraj)
            if (arr>-1){  
                 scoring += 4 ;
                 clback();
            }
       });

    function clback(){
    result = scoring
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TCx6L/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#country, #country-bd').change(function()...
```

Comment: Close but that change alone wouldn't solve it. Thanks for input :)